# How to demonstrate relation between variance and sigma of a half-gaussian distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, variance

Let a [half gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) with this pdf :

[image]

What is the simplest way to demonstrate the following relation between $\sigma$ and the variance ?
$$\sigma =\sqrt{ \frac{variance}{1-\frac{2}{\pi}}}$$

Comment: Starting with what facts?  For instance, if you already know the first absolute moment of the Gaussian distribution, you're almost done.  Otherwise, whatever you do will amount to computing that absolute moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate $\operatorname{var}(Y):=E(Y^2)-[E(Y)]^2$, where $Y$ has the half-gaussian distribution as defined above. It is well known that
$$
Y=\sigma|Z|\tag1
$$
where $Z$ has standard normal distribution, so it is easy to calculate $$E(Y^2)=\sigma^2E(Z^2)=\sigma^2,$$ since the standard normal has variance one.

From (1) you also get $E(Y)=\sigma E(|Z|)$. If you didn't already know that $E|Z|=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$, you can establish this via the integral
$$
E|Z| = 2\int_0^\infty z\left( \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\right)\,dz\tag2
$$
and the substitution $t=z^2/2$.

If (1) is not immediately obvious, you can establish $E(Y)=\sigma\sqrt{\frac2\pi}$ using $E(Y)=\int_0^\infty y\,f_Y(y)\,dy$, which is an integral similar to (2); and establish $E(Y^2)=\sigma^2$ using integration by parts on the integral $\int_0^\infty y^2f_Y(y)\,dy$.